# iOS7-UItableViewCell display in a table view with style Grouped

Tags: ios7

In iOS7 the grouped table view's cell is displayed to full width of the table view more like a plain table view style. But in the settings app of the simulator the grouped style looks different. Could any help with implementing this type of cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'full width' is a default by iOS7, from the Apple's Transition guid:

> Each group extends the full width of the screen.

For the settings, it is not necessary that all apples' controls look standard, You need to do some kind of tweak by your self, maybe put background for the table cells.

Little advice: don't mess the the table nor cell design for now and keep using the standard until the people get used to it.

Answer (score 14):

*This solution will work for iOS7, as well as previous versions of iOS.*

Create a custom UITableView cell class and override UITableViewCell. In setFrame you can adjust desired cell size. Both setFrame and setAlpha are called after tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: so any accessory views and image views display correctly.

reference : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

-(void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  float inset = 20.0f;
  frame.origin.x += inset;
  frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
  [super setFrame:frame];
}
@end
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath replace UITableViewCell with CustomTableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

...

}
```

In your storyboard file set your Prototype cell class to **CustomTableViewCell** and it is identifier to **"CustomTableViewCell"**

[image: IndentedGroupedTableViewCell]

Comment: i think the inset should 10.0f, instead of 20.0f (ios 6, width of grouped tableview is 300px; for ios 7, it's full width 320px). hence (320-300)/2 = 10.0f

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the table view cells in from the edge of the table view by using a custom table cell class and overriding setFrame:. Example code below.

This answer is a based on Aumansoftware's answer (thanks! I would have added this as a comment, but not enough rep). The problem with that answer is that it relies on the calling code setting the frame from scratch, and not making relative changes. This is often true, but not if the caller repeatedly modifies the existing frame. That has the side effect of shrinking the frame horizontally on each call. Turns out, this is exactly what happens when using drag and drop on table rows! So this version just pulls in the edges from the parent view.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
/**
 * Pixel inset off left and right sides.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat sideInset;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self.superview) {
            CGFloat parentWidth = self.superview.frame.size.width;
            if (frame.size.width > (parentWidth - 2.0 * self.sideInset)) {
                    frame.origin.x = self.sideInset;
                    frame.size.width = parentWidth - (2.0f * self.sideInset);
            }
    } else {
            frame.origin.x = self.sideInset;
            frame.size.width = frame.size.width - (2.0f * self.sideInset);
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```