# Subviews of ViewControllers shifted to the left in iOS 7 / XCode 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I've got a project in XCode 5.0 that I ported from XCode 4. Most everything in XCode 5.0 makes sense, but I can't seem to figure out why some subviews of my view controllers are shifted to the left when I compile and run the app.

1.) I have a tableview inside of a view in a view controller. The containing view is freeform portrait with no status bars. It is 520 by 520 in interface builder, centered. When I compile the app, the table view isn't wide enough to fill the width of the view that contains it. The tableview appears to be shifted 30 pixels to the left.

2.) I have disabled auto layout. I hate auto layout for a number of reasons, mostly because I really like to tell Interface builder exactly where things need to go in specific screen configurations. (Please don't preach I just hate relative layout schemes and am willing to do extra work to avoid them).

Does anybody know what might cause the widths of subviews to change in XCode 5.0 ? I have temporarily set the frame manually in the code, but it's really weird because I need to specify a width that is approximately 20 - 30 pixels wider than what I originally had.

Any idea where this difference is coming from?

Comment: None of this would be an Xcode 5 issue. It would be an iOS 7 difference. Xcode is an IDE. The app actually runs under iOS.

Comment: Are you using Autoresize?

Comment: Luis, I noticed that I had "Autoresize subviews" enabled for the view containing the table view. I also had it enabled on the table view itself. Is this the property you are referring to? I attempted to disable it, but it had no effect on the resizing/position of the embedded table view. I disabled on the containing view first, and then I disabled it on both the containing view and the tableview. No effect.

Comment: Back in the old days I filed a report with Apple about issues regarding IB (this was on OS X). They said, unfortunately, some things had to be done by hand. That is the point of auto layout (which is hardly intuitive and frequently feels like wrestling with an octopus - but when it finally does what you want it's pretty sweet). You can either fight it in code or fight it in auto layout -  and either way someone is going to get their eye poked out.

Comment: Haha Lloyd. Yeah. I always turn off Autolayout for the exact reasons you've stated. I don't like it when my apps don't do exactly what I tell them to. It sometimes seems like Autolayout has a mind of its own (not too different from trying to build relative layouts in Android). So this isn't really an autolayout issue. It seems like an XCode / Interface builder issue.

Comment: i get the same issue with Grouped UITableView in iOS 7 now in full width 320px. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783270/ios7-uitableviewcell-display-in-a-table-view-with-style-grouped