# On iOS7, there is no offset between left cell side and add/remove button, and between right cell side and disclosure button

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I attached 2 screenshot of the effect on ios6 and ios7.
we can see on the left side, there is no offset on ios7.
How can I set its position? 
And on the right side, for the disclosure view, there is a same issue.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer, it describes the new behavior of the cells in iOS7.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130287/1001803